# Math or text symbols of Bagua

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, symbols, tikz-styles, text

Is it possible to make math or text symbols of these forms:
[image]

Are there already available in LaTex?

These are from Bagua for your reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sizes can be tailored.  `\bagwd` is the full width of the character, `\baggaph` is the horizontal space on the zero rows, `\baggapv` is the interrow vertical gap of the bagua character, and `\baght` is the height of each of the three black rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength\bagwd
\newlength\baggaph
\newlength\baggapv
\newlength\baght
\setlength\bagwd{1ex}
\setlength\baggaph{.15ex}
\setlength\baggapv{.2ex}
\setlength\baght{.2ex}
\expandafter\def\csname bag0\endcsname{%
  \rule{.5\dimexpr\bagwd-\baggaph\relax}{\baght}%
  \kern\baggaph%
  \rule{.5\dimexpr\bagwd-\baggaph\relax}{\baght}}
\expandafter\def\csname bag1\endcsname{%
  \rule{\bagwd}{\baght}}
\newcommand\bagrow[1]{\csname bag#1\endcsname}
\newcommand\bagua[3]{\setstackgap{S}{\baggapv}%
  \Shortstack{\bagrow#3 \bagrow#2 \bagrow#1}}
\begin{document}
a 
\bagua111
\bagua110
\bagua101
\bagua100
\bagua011
\bagua010
\bagua001
\bagua000
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. Such elegance and the typeset look almost like a canonical textbook answer. ~1

Comment: @wonderich Thank you for the compliment!

Answer (score 5):

The BaGua are also in Unicode, in the Miscellanous Symbols block.

A random sample of fonts:

[image: BaGua]

and so part of the font designer's expression.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand\bagua{☰☱☲☳☴☵☶☷ \iffontchar\font`八 八卦\fi}

\newcommand\namefbga{DejaVu Sans}
\newcommand\namefbgb{FreeMono}
\newcommand\namefbgc{FreeSerif}
\newcommand\namefbgd{Kinryu}
\newcommand\namefbge{Meiryo}
\newcommand\namefbgf{Noto Sans Symbols2}
\newcommand\namefbgg{Quivira}
\newcommand\namefbgh{Sawarabi Gothic}
\newcommand\namefbgi{Sawarabi Mincho}
\newcommand\namefbgj{UKIJ Tughra}

\newfontface\fbga{\namefbga}
\newfontface\fbgb{\namefbgb}
\newfontface\fbgc{\namefbgc}
\newfontface\fbgd{\namefbgd}
\newfontface\fbge{\namefbge}
\newfontface\fbgf{\namefbgf}
\newfontface\fbgg{\namefbgg}
\newfontface\fbgh{\namefbgh}
\newfontface\fbgi{\namefbgi}
\newfontface\fbgj{\namefbgj}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\rowcolor{blue!5}
Font & Bagua \\
\hline
\namefbga\phantom{\Large L} & \fbga\bagua \\
\namefbgb & \fbgb\bagua \\
\namefbgc & \fbgc\bagua \\
\namefbgd & \fbgd\bagua \\
\namefbge & \fbge\bagua \\
\namefbgf & \fbgf\bagua \\
\namefbgg & \fbgg\bagua \\
\namefbgh & \fbgh\bagua \\
\namefbgi & \fbgi\bagua \\
\namefbgj & \fbgj\bagua \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A `tikz`-based solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {tikz}

\newcommand{\bagua}[1]
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.4ex,y=0.4ex,line width=0.15ex]
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\number{#1}
    \foreach\i in {1,2,3}
    {%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\digit{Mod(div(\number,pow(10,\i-1)),10)}
      \ifnum\digit = 0
        \draw (0  ,3-\i) --++ (1,0);
        \draw (1.5,3-\i) --++ (1,0);
      \else
        \draw (0  ,3-\i) --++ (2.5,0);
      \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}% <-- This prevents more space
}

\begin{document}

a
\bagua{111}
\bagua{110}
\bagua{101}
\bagua{100}
\bagua{011}
\bagua{010}
\bagua{001}
\bagua{000}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks I really like your answer, but I already awarded the answer to the other person. But I made a new question maybe you can answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/605410/41144 to get extra bonus.

Comment: also +1 voted up, great work