# Math or text symbols of Bagua 2

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, symbols, tikz-styles, text

Previously, we had obtained great answers to get [math or text symbols of Bagua](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/605332/math-or-text-symbols-of-bagua).

Is it possible to make math or text symbols of these forms of Bagua (as 90 degree rotations of the previous ones):

[image]

Are there already available in LaTex?

These are from Bagua for your reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A general approach is to use `\rotatebox` from the [`graphicx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package.  You can take any answer from the last question and wrap it in `\rotatebox{90}{...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost the same solution as my prevoius one. I added a second parameter to the macro that takes values 0/1 for not rotating/rotating (90 degrees). I changed slightly the dimensions too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {tikz}

\newcommand{\bagua}[2] % symbol number, rotation: 0 horizontal / 1 vertical
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90*#2,x=1ex,y=1ex,line width=0.15ex]
    \def\d{1.345}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\number{#1}
    \useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \foreach\i in {1,2,3}
    {%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\digit{Mod(div(\number,pow(10,\i-1)),10)}
      \ifnum\digit = 0
        \draw (0  ,\d-0.425*\i) --++ (0.4,0);
        \draw (0.6,\d-0.425*\i) --++ (0.4,0);
      \else
        \draw (0  ,\d-0.425*\i) --++ (1,0);
      \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}% <-- This prevents more space
}

\begin{document}
\huge 

a
\bagua{111}{0}
\bagua{110}{0}
\bagua{101}{0}
\bagua{100}{0}
\bagua{011}{0}
\bagua{010}{0}
\bagua{001}{0}
\bagua{000}{0}

a
\bagua{111}{1}
\bagua{110}{1}
\bagua{101}{1}
\bagua{100}{1}
\bagua{011}{1}
\bagua{010}{1}
\bagua{001}{1}
\bagua{000}{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks I just wanted to thank you and reward your genius on this. +1

Answer (score 5):

How about the following quick modification from the tikz-based solution of your previous question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {tikz}

\newcommand{\bagua}[1]
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.4ex,y=0.4ex,line width=0.15ex]
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\number{#1}
    \foreach\i in {1,2,3}
    {%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\digit{Mod(div(\number,pow(10,\i-1)),10)}
      \ifnum\digit = 0
        \draw (3-\i,  0) --++ (0,1);
        \draw (3-\i,1.5) --++ (0,1);
      \else
        \draw (3-\i,  0) --++ (0,2.5);
      \fi
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}% <-- This prevents more space
}
\begin{document}

a
\bagua{111}
\bagua{110}
\bagua{101}
\bagua{100}
\bagua{011}
\bagua{010}
\bagua{001}
\bagua{000}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks +1, I awarded the person who did the earlier job.

Comment: @wonderich, sure. good choice!!